# Android - if statement not executing

Tags: java, android

I'm following the Mr. Nom tutorial from Beginning Android Game e-book,
and in the part which recognizes where a touch was made, the if statement doesn't execute even though the condition in true.

I ran the debugger and checked the values. the if is something like

```
if(event.x >0 && event.x <64 && event.y>416 && event.y<480)
```

but even with values like
event.x = 15
event.y = 450
(got from the debugger)
it won't get within the curly brackets of the if statement.
the requested image is in the bottom left corner of the portrait screen.

any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `event.x = 15` and `event.y = 450`, then the condition

```
event.x >0 && event.x <64 && event.y>416 && event.y<480
```

evaluates to true. Something else must be wrong in your code. (Perhaps the branch *is* executed, just that you don't see the effect of it for some reason.) Please post more code, or even better, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

To debug the situation, I'd suggest you break up the expression and do something like

```
Log.I("...", "cond1: " + (event.x >   0));
Log.I("...", "cond2: " + (event.x <  64));
Log.I("...", "cond3: " + (event.y > 416));
Log.I("...", "cond4: " + (event.y < 480));
```

Comment: I added a breakpoint to the line after the if condition, it won't stop.

What else could be wrong to prevent it from entering an if statement?
some settings or something? so i'd know what part of code to paste